# WCF and Windows authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to get a WCF service set up on our server using windows authentication and IIS 7. When calling the service I get the following error message.

Cannot open database "TestDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

Here is my config file for the WCF service.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="binBulletin">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="BulletinBoardService.BulletinBehavior"
          name="BulletinBoardService.BulletinService">
          <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binBulletin"
            name="epBulletin_Basic" contract="BulletinBoardService.IBulletinService">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binBulletin"
            name="epBulletin_Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="BulletinBoardService.BulletinBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you need to add impersonation enabled on your web.config for your IIS7 hosted site. Something ~ `<identity impersonate="true" />`

Comment: to format code or XML, select it in the editor and press Control-K. Also, please leave out the "Hi" and "Thanks". This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so we're not having a discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grant access permission in the SQL Server for the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` account  if you use local SQL Server or for `DomainName\AspNetServer$` (where AspNetServer is the name of the server where IIS7 are running). For details see for example the last section of  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx.

`UPDATED`: First of all you should don't forget to configure virtual directory of IIS to switch on "Windows Authentication" and switch off "Anonymous Authentication".

I am not sure that `basicHttpBinding` is the best choice for you. You wrote almost nothing about your WCF service so I can't recommend you a way. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734769.aspx for example to see which ways you can choose.

To access a local DB you can use user impersonation. It can be implemented either generally per WFC call or you can do temporary impersonation before accessing of DB. (see http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/04/17/impersonate-a-clients-identity-in-wcf/ for example for details).

The main problem is that there are no **best way** to access database from a service. If you choose impersonation for example. It can looks like nice because inside of database one sees from which user the request come. But in a lot of real situation the usage of impersonation not really solve a problem, but only forward it. Who should administrate permission inside of the database? With respect of which tool one should grant permission to users. Who makes user administration in your corporation? Do one only user administration inside of Active Directory or do one also administration of SQL Server databases? So because of existing processes in your corporation the user impersonation could be not the best choice.

There are a lot of different scenarios to access DB from WCF. For example in the last project which I implemented I wrote a WCF service which has a lot of methods. Inside of every method direct at the beginning of the method I used Microsoft Authorization Manager API to verify whether the user has permission for the corresponding operation or not. One used Authorization Manager Snap-In to grant permission to user through assigning it to some application role. And for accessing to the database I used one user account (like `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` in your case). Nevertheless the solution was secure and one had a tool for the user administration which corresponds to business requirements.

I have too less information about you environment and business requirements to give you one recommendation. I want only explain that you probably need to make a security concept of your solution based on different possibilities which you have.

Comment: I don't think (this is an assumption) that it won't work for this guy; I think he wants the service to log onto the database under the user's account.  Otherwise, this solution is the easiest to implement.

Comment: Yes, I want the user account to be passed to the database and not NT Authority\Network Service.

Comment: @Will: We have here a really standard situation: a WCF-Service rutting under a standard Application Pool under `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` account. The service try to access TestDB database. Everything is standard. So one need only grant permission in DB. We have no information about the DB and about the security environment. First of all the service must running. If we will know moreabout the environment, then one can give more advices to make the solution more secure.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't see your answer before. Do use use local DB or on a remote computer? Do you have a intranet or internet environment?

Comment: We're using a local DB in a intranet environment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but I had this problem.  The problem was due to the identity setting of the Application Pool that my service was using in IIS.  If you set the appropriate identity there, you should be good. In my case, the default was set to NT Authority\Network Service.